# I'm trying to create a series of random numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script here that I created to generate a string of random numbers. I do not know how to make it where the numbers would be random every time it is used. For instance I want it to be like this:

0,1,2,3,5
1,4,7,3,5
2,8,2,1,3

Instead I am getting:

0,1,2,3,5
1,1,2,3,5
2,1,2,3,5

The first number is running in sequence which is great. But I need the other 4 numbers to change.

```
inter1rand = random.randint(1, 1)
inter1time = inter1rand
inter1 = inter1time
print (inter1)  

inter2rand = random.randint(24, 31)
inter2time = inter2rand + inter1time
inter2 = inter2time
print (inter2)

inter3rand = random.randint(34, 55)
inter3time = inter3rand + inter2time
inter3 = inter3time
print (inter3)


mouse1 = random.randint(110, 1100)
mouse2 = random.randint(875, 1100)
mouse3 = random.randint(375, 607)



col_list1 = [str(n) + ',1,' + str(mouse1) + ',' + str(mouse2) + ',' + str(mouse3) + ';' for n in range(0,inter1)]
col_list2 = [str(n) + ',1,' + str(mouse1) + ',' + str(mouse2) + ',' + str(mouse3) + ';' for n in range(inter1,inter2)]
col_list3 = [str(n) + ',1,' + str(mouse1) + ',' + str(mouse2) + ',' + str(mouse3) + ';' for n in range(inter2,inter3)]
#print (col_list1)
#print (col_list1 + col_list2)
#print (col_list1 + col_list2 + col_list3)
```

Comment: `secrets` is a module that'll give you truly random numbers. But it seems like you're making random lists. use numpy's random module

Comment: with numpy I can do both random as well as sequential numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code from using mouse1, mouse2 and mouse3 to directly use random.randint:

```
col_list1 = [str(n) + ',1,' + str(random.randint(110, 1100)) + ',' + str(random.randint(875, 1100)) + ',' + str(random.randint(375, 607)) + ';' for n in range(0,inter1)]
col_list2 = [str(n) + ',1,' + str(random.randint(110, 1100)) + ',' + str(random.randint(875, 1100)) + ',' + str(random.randint(375, 607)) + ';' for n in range(inter1,inter2)]
col_list3 = [str(n) + ',1,' + str(random.randint(110, 1100)) + ',' + str(random.randint(875, 1100)) + ',' + str(random.randint(375, 607)) + ';' for n in range(inter2,inter3)]
```

Comment: This is correct, you are setting mouse1-3 to a fixed integer then using them multiple times, this fix generates new randoms every time

Answer (score 0):

If you want truly random integer values you can check out **[np.random.choice()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)** function also.

```
np.random.choice(10,3)
array([9, 4, 2])
>>> np.random.choice(10,3)
array([6, 7, 8])
>>> np.random.choice(31,3)
array([11, 28, 10])
>>> np.random.choice([0,1],3)
array([0, 1, 1])
```

In this function you might not get to give range but chances of repetition is less.

Answer (score 0):

Use the random module, and its `randint`:

```
import random

for u in range(3):
    r = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)]
    for d in r[:-1]:
        print(d, end=', ')
    print(r[-1])
```

Returns:

```
9, 6, 0, 4, 1
7, 9, 2, 2, 1
4, 10, 6, 5, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, I've linked ***some*** of the ways sources below:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/generating-random-number-list-in-python
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.random.html